# Expresion Regular en Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need help you for write this expresion regular to Postgresql.

This work perfectly in C#, but I need this for Postgresql:

```
^[\S]*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W_])[\S]{8,15}$
```

I need validate a word that have one or more digit and one or more letter and one or more special caracters. and large between 8 and 15

Comment: It seems to me your regex if off even in C#. Also, PostgreSQL regex is rather powerful, its ARE is capable of running lookaheads. I think you may use the same regex, maybe just alter it a bit, say, to `^(?=[^[:lower:]]*[[:lower:]])(?=[^[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]])(?=\D*\d)(?=[[:alnum:]]*[^[:alnum:]])\S{8,15}$`

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to match using regex. You can find the Postgres documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html). It seems to me like you can use the POSIX regex operator `~`.

There are other variants such as `~*` which is case insensitive and the same two with the not operator in front, `!~` and `!~*`.

Ex:

```
SELECT *
  FROM strings s
 WHERE s.string ~ '^[\S]*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W_])[\S]{8,15}$'
;
```

---

There are also pattern matching string functions such as, `REGEXP_MATCHES` and `REGEXP_REPLACE`, that can be found in the same documentation.

Ex_2:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(s.string, '^[\S]*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W_])[\S]{8,15}$')[0] -- note the index
  FROM strings s
;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, but i can not work with your help, i dont get correct answer when use 'D@niel123+) for this cases:

1) SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('D@niel123+', '^\S(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[\d])(?=.*[\W_])[\S]{8,15}$')

2) SELECT 'D@niel123+' ~ E'^(?=[^[:lower:]][[:lower:]])(?=[^[:upper:]][[:upper:]])(?=\D*\d)(?=[[:alnum:]]*[^[:alnum:]])\S{8,15}$';

3) SELECT 'D@niel123+' ~ E'^\S(.[A-Z])(.[\d])(.*[\W_])[\S]{2,15}$';